# How to check whether or not an integer is a perfect square?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to Python, and I'm trying to check whether or not an integer submitted by the  user is a perfect square, and this is what I came up with:

```
import math
number=int(input("Insert number here: "))
root= math.sqrt(number)
if isinstance(root, int):
    print("This number is a perfect square!")
else:
    print("This number is not a perfect square!")
```

Now, I understand that the problem is that, if i were to input `9`, the program would store root as `3.0`, which would make it a floating point. But how can I fix this?

Comment: `if int(root) == root`.

Comment: btw, you problem is with the `isinstance` method - it returns a float type

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly